# ADT - Android SDK manager shows update installed with a red mark

Tags: android, macos, adt

I am using ADT with Eclipse on MacOSX. Yesterday, after I installed some updates via the Android SDK manager, the IDE no longer recognizes the SDK. In the SDK, the update shows being installed with a red mark.

[image]

After I install the SDK build-tools 17. Still not work in ADT

[image]

The sdk path is correct, I can open sdk manager from menu of eclipse. BTW, when I open eclipse it display a message like this, but nothing when I press check for updates

[image]

Comment: did u check preferance path?

Answer (score 2):

This mostly occurs because the IDE is incapable of finding the path where the android SDK is installed. Check if the path set in your IDE is the correct path, try setting that manually by going to

```
 Window - Preferences - Android - SDK Location and setup SDK path.
```

then go to:

```
Window > Preferences > General > Startup and shutdown: Check "Android development toolkit"
```

& restart eclipse from `File` menu.

Comment: Looks like a bug in eclipse to me. Try to uninstall the SDK and adt bundle and re-install again.

Answer (score 0):

It's new update of Android SDK manager to indicate installed platforms.. Nothing to worry about that. Update Android build tool 17 also.Surely it will work.

Comment: I added more info in the question, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

i your picture the build tools are not installed first install them and restart eclipse and enjoy and if any other problem comes type in commments

Comment: I added more info in the question, please take a look

Comment: first install build tools which is not installed